# Xamarin Android APP crashes after splash screen

Tags: android, xamarin.android, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I used Visual Studio Team Service to build my android xamarin app. Build works fine but if I deploy the apk to my phone it crashed after the logon screen.
If I try to create the apk file with visual studio Archive Manager and the deploy the created apk it works fine. What can be the difference between my local created apk and the apk from the build server? Keystore files are the same. Any suggestions?

This is my sign configuration
[image]

And this my build configuration
[image]
[image]

### UPDATE 1:

I used the hosted build. Now i created a test project (create new black androud project in visual studio 15.1) and uncommented this  line SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

Same result like in my other project the app crashes after start. I think it is not a problem of the code but a problem of the build or sign

UPDATE 2: 
Changed Hosted Build to Hosted VS2017
[image]

[image]

Comment: provide your code to help you

Comment: Which build agent you used? Hosted agent or on premise build agent on your machine? If you are using on premise build agent, what's the result if you build the app on that build agent manually via MSBuild tool? Could you reproduce that issue with a new project? On the other hand, the source code is at here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/XamarinAndroid/XamarinAndroid.ps1

Comment: @starain-MSFT added some details in my inital post

Comment: What's the detail build log? Can you share it on the  onedrive?

Comment: @starain-MSFT https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah3R-cbwVaIVkZ9cEgolajjal_s97g

Comment: You are using nuget 3.3, please use Nuget 4.0 instead. Also, share the detail build log that build in Visual Studio. (Get detail build log: Tool >Options >Project and Solution> Build and Run>MSBuild project build output verbosity: detail.

Comment: @starain-MSFT Changed on build server to nuget 4.0. Always the same error. here my vs-build log https://1drv.ms/t/s!Ah3R-cbwVaIVka9JZufe7x9cD5asIw

Comment: Do you use Hosted VS2017 agent, which have VS 2017 installed. Hosted agent just have VS 2015 installed. Based on the build log of VSTS, it uses MSBuild 14.0 instead of 15.0. So, use Hosted VS2017 agent instead.

Comment: @starain-MSFT changed to VS2017 anf MS Build 15. Doesn't change. App crash on startup

Comment: Share the newest build log on the OneDrive.

Comment: @starain-MSFT here it is https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah3R-cbwVaIVka9L7sCwGk9Dz3CGTA

Comment: @starain-MSFT any news? thanks christoph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue and it was resolved enabling the ZipAlign option on the Signing Task, maybe it is what you need to do too.

[image]

Comment: yeah! thanks. but why I need this option @starain-MSFT?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that it's necessary when you build using a Release configuration, [Android ZipAlign](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/zipalign.html). As the documentation state _This tool should always be used to align your APK file before distributing it to end-users._

Comment: This did not fix for us. Any ideas furthering this @LoéLobo? At a complete stand still.

Comment: Hi @jtth, I'm not working with Xamarin for some time now, I wouldn't have a clue why even with ZipAlign enabled you still have the same behavior, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling "Zipalign" works for me!

Comment: From where I can enable Zipalign. Please write the steps. I am using visual studio 2017